# Python Beautiful Soup parse a table using class

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to python and trying to extract a table from a page but I can't find the table using BS4. Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website_url = requests.get('https://chartink.com/screener/copy-supertrend-negative-breakout-1103').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'table table-striped scan_results_table dataTable no-footer'})
My_table
```

Comment: first check if you have table in `website_url.text` or `soup`. Next try to use `find('table')` without other options. AND don't forget to use `print()` to display result - `print(My_table)`. Maybe there is no table with these classes

Comment: I checked HTML in code and I don't see table with this class. Maybe page uses JavaScript to create this table - but requests and BS can't run JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I couldn't find it in html too but I could find the class when I inspect the page.

Comment: so page uses JavaScript to add this. You may need [Selenium-Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript and then you can get this HTML. Or you can even use Selenium's function to search in HTML.

Comment: Sir is it legal to access Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

That content is added dynamically through a POST request returning json. It requires authentication via cookies and headers. Simpler may be to use selenium. Grab the element by id and pass its outerHTML to read_html to convert to nice table output

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://chartink.com/screener/copy-supertrend-negative-breakout-1103')
table = pd.read_html(d.find_element_by_id('DataTables_Table_0').get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
print(table)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Sir is it legal to access Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

soup.find('table') gives the following

```
 <table style="margin: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a class="selected" href="">INK CHART :</a></td>
<td style="width: 220px;">
<input class="selector" id="searchbox" name="selector" onblur="clearTimeout(ctime)" onfocus="init()" onkeyup="refresh()" style="width: 100%" type="text"/>
<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" id="DivShim" style="display:none;position: absolute;"></iframe>
<div class="sbox" id="sbox" style="z-index: 10; ">
</div>
</td>
<td style="width: 120px;">
<select class="up" name="type" style="width: 100%">
<option value="can">Candle-Stick</option>
<option value="po">Point and Figure</option>
<option value="fundamentals">Fundamentals</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<input class="search_button" type="submit" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Since this is not what you want, you will need to use selenium or splash. 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this will help with @mrcool4's question.

Comment: Thanks David, Could you please let me know why requests isn't working with this page?

Comment: It is working, but this page likely uses javascript to load this item. This is a very common issue with scraping.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the Selenium module.